# Django: Get list from html form

Tags: python, html, django, list

Here it's my django code

```
def postData(request):
    itemQuantity = request.POST.getlist('itemQuantity')
    print itemQuantity
```

following is my html code

```
<form action="/test/data/" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="itemQuantity" id="" style="width:350px;" value="{{itemQuantity}}">
<center><input type="submit" style="background-color:#00B16A; padding: 4px; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid #999; margin-top:5px;" value="Login"></center>
</form>
```

here it's my output

```
[u"[u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'6']"]
```

expected output is

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6]
```

Comment: I hate to sound like Alex Trebec but this doesn't really seem like a question.

Comment: May I know the purpose of including itemQuantity list hidden in your form

Comment: It looks like you are putting a list into a list - what kind of model field is feeding `{{ itemQuantity }}`? Did you try just a regular `request.POST.get('itemQuantity' or None)`?

Comment: Yep.  HTML forms return strings.  You need to convert the contents of those strings to integers if you expect them to be integers (and also prepared for the possibility that what the form return was not integers no matter how much you insist they should be).